# How to use setTimeout to step through a for loop line by line?

Tags: javascript, algorithm, sorting, animation, settimeout

I am trying to visualize a bubble sort algorithm, I am trying to figure out a way to make my for loop iterate once every 1000ms, so it steps through and I am able to draw the result of each iteration.

I have tried using setTimeout but the for loop continues to execute while the setTimeout executes asynchronously. Is there another way to just "step" through the for loop?

```
// bubble sort
function bubbleSort(arr) {
  for (let i = 0; i < arr.length; i++) {
    for (let j = 0; j < arr.length; j++) {
      if (arr[j] > arr[j + 1]) {
        let temp = arr[j];
        arr[j] = arr[j + 1];
        arr[j + 1] = temp;
        delay();
      }
    }
  }
  return arr;
}
function delay() {
  setTimeout(() => {
    console.log('hello');
  }, 1000);
}
```

Comment: Make a generator function.

Comment: I updated my code to show something more along the lines of what you were originally trying to accomplish.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can convert your function to a [generator function](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Statements/function*) and yield the state of the array after each sort.

If you try to call `.next().value`, when the outer-loop is finished, an exception will be thrown. This is where you can catch it and cancel the interval.

```js
console.log('START');

let arr = [ 5, 3, 4, 2, 1 ],
    gen = bubbleSort(arr),
    wait = 1000,
    counter = 0;

const intervalId = setInterval(() => {
  try {
    const value = gen.next().value.join(',');
    console.log(`Step ${++counter}: ${value}`);
  } catch (e) {
    clearInterval(intervalId);
    console.log('STOP');
  }
}, wait);

function* bubbleSort(arr) {
  for (let i = 0; i < arr.length; i++) {
    for (let j = 0; j < arr.length; j++) {
      if (arr[j] > arr[j + 1]) {
        let temp = arr[j];
        arr[j] = arr[j + 1];
        arr[j + 1] = temp;
        yield arr;
      }
    }
  }
}
```

```css
.as-console-wrapper { top: 0; max-height: 100% !important; }
```

---

Alternatively, you can try adding a callback that starts a timeout that will return in a linear fashion.

```js
let arr = [ 5, 3, 4, 2, 1 ], wait = 1000;

const stepFn = (step, arr) => {
  const finalStep = Math.pow(arr.length, 2) - 1;
  const result = arr.join(','); // Capture values
  setTimeout(() => {
    console.log(`Step ${step}: ${result}`); // Finally display them
    if (step === finalStep) { console.log('STOP'); }
  }, step * wait); // Asynchronous calls, but the timeout is linear
};

console.log('START');
bubbleSort(arr, stepFn);

function bubbleSort(arr, callback) {
  for (let i = 0; i < arr.length; i++) {
    for (let j = 0; j < arr.length; j++) {
      if (arr[j] > arr[j + 1]) {
        let temp = arr[j];
        arr[j] = arr[j + 1];
        arr[j + 1] = temp;
      }
      callback(i * arr.length + j, arr); // Insert a callback
    }
  }
}
```

```css
.as-console-wrapper { top: 0; max-height: 100% !important; }
```